# Heredar CSS de Objeto en jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Estoy utilizando una librería llamada [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io), tienen una funcionalidad de arrastrar elementos desde un panel para añadirlos al calendario, favor miren este [ejemplo](https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/demos/external-dragging.html).

Según el mismo ejemplo esta función hereda el título de la tarjeta externa.

```
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {
  $(this).data('event', {
    title: $.trim($(this).text()), // Hereda el título de la tarjeta externa
    stick: true
  });
  $(this).draggable({
    zIndex: 999,
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 0
  });
});
```

Adaptando la misma solución para la empresa apliqué diferentes clases a cada elemento externo, diferenciando nombres y colores, tengo algo así:
[image: Agenda con FullCalendar]

El problema es que al arrastrar cualquier objeto sólo logro que herede el nombre y no la clase:

[image: No respeta la clase (CSS)]

Si en la función añado:

```
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {
      $(this).data('event', {
        title: $.trim($(this).text()), // Hereda el título de la tarjeta externa
        color: 'lc', //Tengo clases que heredan de .fc-event
        stick: true
      });
      $(this).draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 0
      });
    });
```

Respeta el color, pero para todos. Finalmente, así como hereda el texto de la tarjeta, deseo que herede el className.

Comment: Dentro del `fullCalendar({})` tenés la opción de obtener el evento [`drop()`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/drop) y [`eventDrop()`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop), probablemente tengas que revisar esa documentación y algún parámetro te deje modificar la clase cuando se copia.

Comment: @Kleith también probé eso, utilizando

`$("#external-events .fc-event").css("background-color");`

y muchas otras variantes.